# Argument principle and the principle branch of the complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I've just been reading about complex analysis and came across the Cauchy argument principle.

In my understanding you are taking the contour integral of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ around a designated path.

If you define the principle branch of the logarithm $L(z)$, then it is well established that $\frac{d}{dz} L(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

Similarly, if you were to have $\frac{d}{dz} L(f(z))$, then by the complex chain rule, you would have $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$, no?

Correct me if I am wrong up to this point. So, is it wrong to phrase the Cauchy argument principle as:

$\oint \frac{dL(f(z))}{dz} dz $

Furthermore, if the contour you choose were to be simply connected, positively oriented curve, and the function itself is holomorphic, the contour integral can be transformed into a Riemann integral:

$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dL(f(z(t)))}{dz} \frac{dz}{dt} dt$

Now, by the chain rule, is it incorrect to then conclude that this is equal to:

$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dL(f(z(t)))}{dt} dt$

=$L(f(z(b)))-L(f(z(a)))$

I am almost certain that the final conclusion is wrong, but I just cannot see where I went wrong. I know that the principal branch requires that you restrict $-π<Im(z)<π$, so that no two numbers differ by $2πi$, but if one were able to impose this limitation along the contour, does the relationship hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $L(f(z))$ is discontinuous at any $z$ where $f(z)$ lies on the branch cut of $L$, and that prevents you from making sense of $\frac{d}{dz}L(f(z))$. At best you'll end up with some non-trivial contour where $L(f(z))$ is discontinuous, and you won't be able to choose that contour because of starting with a fixed logarithm $L$. However, if you are able to break your contour into pieces that don't cross the branch, but can end on side of the branch, then what you wrote will work; but each piece gives you two evaluation terms. If you obtained a wrong answer, it was probably because you glossed over some place where $f(\gamma(t))$ crossed the fixed branch of your logarithm $L$, and you missed the difference of evaluation terms from the two sides of the branch of $L(f(z))$.